# break when empty line from a File

Tags: python

I have file contains text like `Hello:World`

```
#!/usr/bin/python
f = open('m.txt')
while True:
    line = f.readline()
    if not line :
          break
    first  = line.split(':')[0]
    second = line.split(':')[1] 
f.close()
```

I want to put the string after splitting it into 2 variables

On the second iteration i get error

> List index out of range

it doesn't break when the line is empty , i searched the answer on related topics and the solution was

```
if not line:
           print break
```

But it does not work

Comment: I ran your code, no errors for me :/  Are you sure you have `m.txt` in the same folder?

Answer (score 0):

If there's lines after an empty line (or your text editor inserted an empty line at the end of the file), it's not actually empty. It has a new line character and/or carriage return

You need to strip it off

```
with open('m.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        if not line.strip(): 
            break

        first, second = line.split(':')
```

Comment: there is no line after the empty line

Comment: Well, still, `if not line` isn't checking what you think is. Plus, make sure you've saved your file before running that code

Answer (score 0):

You can do this relatively easily by utilizing an optional feature of the built-in [`iter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#iter) function by passing it a second argument (called *`sentinel`* in the docs) that will cause it to stop if the value is encountered while iterating.

Here's what how use it to make the line processing loop terminate if  an empty line is encountered:

```
with open('m.txt') as fp:
    for line in iter(fp.readline, ''):
        first, second  = line.rstrip().split(':')
        print(first, second)
```

Note the `rstrip()` which removes the newline at the end of each line read.

Answer (score -2):

Your code is fine, I can't put a picture in a comment.  It all works, here:

[image]

Comment: Ohhh i cannot understand how !

Comment: I wonder why this got voted down, pretty sure this will help the OP

Comment: Please don't upload images. And answers with "that works" aren't very useful because then the question doesn't make sense

Comment: I can put it in as text however I'm simply illustrating his exact code works, perhaps it will point him in the right direction?